# How would I go about creating a list of Textbox items to use in other methods?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a series of 5 text boxes on a winforms form which are used to collect data as strings. I intend to use these boxes in multiple ways from a method to clear the contents of each, to a method which takes the data from each to check before exporting to a text file.

In order to do this I planned to create a `List<Textbox>` which would essentially be a list of all 5 boxes so I could later use code such as

```
foreach(Texbox box in *texboxList*)
{
    box.Clear()
}
```

etc.

My only idea so far is to create a seperate method which adds all of the boxes to a list and then somehow pass the result of the method as a parameter to the relevant methods such as those that clear the boxes. The code I currently have is displayed below.

```
public List<TextBox> Clear_entered_data()
{
    List<TextBox> textBoxes = new List<TextBox>();
    textBoxes.Add(tbox1);
    textBoxes.Add(tbox2);
    textBoxes.Add(tbox3);
    textBoxes.Add(tbox4);
    textBoxes.Add(tbox5);
    return textBoxes;
}
```

This is the code I'm using to generate the list of textboxes to use. I think the problem I'm having is understanding how this can be passed to other methods through parameters. The method I'd like to make use of the list is shown below here as I have it so far.

```
private void Clear_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, List<TextBox> textBoxes)
  {

    DialogResult Clear_validation = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you would like to clear all data from the form?","Clear data?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

    if(Clear_validation == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        foreach (TextBox box in textBoxes)
        {
            box.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

With the code above I get the error upon running :

'Error  1   No overload for 'Clear_button_Click' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler''

But I've had no luck, please try and explain whats going wrong and help me find  more appropriate solution!

Thanks

Comment: "But I've had no luck, please try and explain whats going wrong" -- first you have to tell us what is going wrong before we can explain it to you.

Comment: Clear_entered_data() looks like it could be called something more appropriate  - e.g. GetAllTextboxes().

Comment: That's exactly how you would build a `List<TextBox>` from five `TextBox` objects.  (Though it might make more sense to put it in a property with a backing field that holds the list, so you don't re-create it every time.  A property will likely be semantically more clear than a method as well.  Especially if you name it something... less misleading.)  If this isn't working in some way, you need to explain the problem.

Comment: Edited above to clarify the problem. Apologies for the method name, I originally had the method to just `tbox1.Clear();` etc. for each box before thinking of making a list. It was just missed when I was trying to sort the list problems out

Answer (score 0):

create a private class member that of list of textboxes `List<TextBox> _textBoxes;`

then after you call InitializeComponents(because before that your textboxex doesn't exists if you used the IDE to create them) place your code to add the textboxes into the list

```
 _textBoxes = new List<TextBox>();
 _textBoxes.Add(tbox1);
 _textBoxes.Add(tbox2);
 _textBoxes.Add(tbox3);
 _textBoxes.Add(tbox4);
 _textBoxes.Add(tbox5);
```

now you can use in your methods the _textBoxes that contains all your created TextBox

your public List Clear_entered_data() became

```
public List<TextBox> ClearTextBoxes() {
    foreach(var textBox in _textBoxes){
       textBox.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution sounds promising and looks like it should be what I need, however I'm not entirely sure what you mean by 'create a private class member that of list of textboxes'. I don't know how I would go about that

Answer (score 0):

If you used a naming convention, you could just iterate over the form's control collection like this - in my example, the names all start with "SpecialTextBox":

```
foreach(Control c in someFormReference.Controls)
{
    if (c.GetType() == typeof(TextBox) && c.Name.StartsWith("SpecialTextBox"))
    {
        // do your thing here
    }
}
```

Comment: if you want to automate which textboxe to use you can even use the .Tag property of the textbox

Comment: Would the form's `Controls` collection contain a reference to the `TextBox` if it's nested within another control?  If not, this is pretty limited.  And not really necessary anyway, since the code in the question implies that the references to the 5 `TextBox` objects are already known.